# Imagemagick arbitrary size/ratio gradient

Tags: image-processing, imagemagick

Is it possible to apply a smooth diagonal gradient overlay from left bottom corner to right upper corner *preserving original colors* as below?

[image]

Might sound as a simple task but the actual image size is not known in prior.

Comment: I do not understand the question. What does the gradient have to do with "preserving original colors". You can easily make a diagonal gradient with two colors using Imagemagick and then use that to add color to an underlying image. See https://imagemagick.org/Usage/canvas/#diagonal_gradients. Please clarify your question or show a input and output image for the result you want. Also what version of Imagemagick and platform/OS are you using.

Comment: You cannot add a two-color gradient to your image and preserve all the input image colors at every pixel. There is no way to do that.  You could use a mask image to make, say the middle no change and add the gradient colors to the corners. That is possble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this is what you want. Using Imagemagick 6, I create a diagonal gradient with blue in the lower left corner and red in upper right corner and then blend 20%/80% with the original with the gradient.

Imagemagick automatically gets the dimensions of the (cloned/copied) image from %w and %h using the -sparse-color barycentric syntax for creating a gradient. See https://imagemagick.org/Usage/canvas/#diagonal_gradients

input:
[image]

```
convert input.jpg \
\( +clone -sparse-color barycentric '0,%h blue  %w,0 red' +write gradient.jpg \) \
-define compose:args=20,80 -compose blend -composite \
result.jpg
```

[image]

In the above, I saved the gradient image just to show it has been created properly:

[image]

Alternately, you can set the alpha channel of the gradient to 20% and use compose over.

```
convert input.jpg \
\( +clone -sparse-color barycentric '0,%h blue  %w,0 red' -alpha set -channel alpha -evaluate set 20% +channel \) \
-compose over -composite \
result2.jpg
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry for being not enough clear in details. You were absolutely right in doubting the question. Tried to find same effects among your scripts by searching for gradient but with no luck. Anyway this is exactly what I wanted to get as a result! Also a lot of thanks for mentioning the -sparse-color barycentric syntax!

Comment: You are right, I do not have any script that will do just that. But the command is not so complex that it needs a script, though I could create one. I do have a script for making multi-color gradients.

Comment: Yes, at the very beginning one just can't see the whole path and all tasks do seem complex, even simple ones. Moreover you always offer 2-3 possible solutions with its own pros and cons, so a separate script might combine them and act depending on user's inputs and hiding all the hard work under the hood. Thanks again!

Comment: The two methods should produce identical results in this example. There is a scroll bar for the command section. This forum seems to prefer that one use the scroll mechanism rather than just text for the code.

Comment: Got it! Also if I add the third point e.g. `'0,%h blue %[fx:w/2],%[fx:h/2] green %w,0 red'`, then I get like V-shaped gradient, where blue color completely fills the bottom part. Is it even a correct syntax? Could you please point me to the docs regarding the barycentric syntax where I can read more about it?